# move generated google Form to specific google drive folder using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am creating a few forms using Google Apps Script which automatically generates in my root (*My Drive*) of my Google Drive.

I want to **move** these forms to a specific folder of a **Shared Drive**.

I googled about moving files (or any object) to another folder, most of them are suggesting that *copy the file to a specific location, then delete from the source location*.

But in this case, *my **formIds** are **changing*** which I don't want to change.

Is there any better way to move files (in my case Forms) to another location in Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you should always favor canonical sources over 3rd party tutorials that pop-up in google search. The official documentation for the Drive API has guides describing how to move files from one drive folder to the next. [I suggest you start there](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder).

Answer (score 0):

the following code should work for moving any file, including forms, to a destination folder in Google Drive:

```
var fileId = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; //<--replace string with your file ID
var destinationFolderId = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba0987654321';//<--replace string with your destination folder ID

function moveFile(fileId,destinationFolderId) {
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(destinationFolder);
}
```